# How to use multiple databases for Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails application which is using PostgreSQL database and a huge user base is expected. Is there a way to use multiple databases, may be one database for Read operations and other for Write operations.

Any suggestions/solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it via database clustering. Master database and slave database. Try using amazon RDS or Heroku services.

Answer (score 1):

Use database sharding. Try using Master and slave databases.

Octopus is a really useful gem for that. https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus